# git log range but only include one path of commits

Tags: git

I want to see the log of only reachable commits between two commits i.e. not *all* commits in chronological order, just following each commit to its parent from the start to the end.

For example, with this (partial) commit graph

```
*   commit 10d0e777e5e660d1c51d9a4f60cdcd5891642b33
|\  Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:46:52 2020 -0400
| |     Merge branch 'branch'
| | 
| * commit ddcc7634e5bbc3d5ebeb67dcbc0cbcafa74aa67e
| | Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:46:41 2020 -0400
| |     last branch commit
| | 
* | commit ac6978892337b20f2548f20d1ad6e0376d609cdb
| | Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:45:11 2020 -0400
| |     merged another branch
| | 
| * commit 5e86079548fdd3610b80a946cf1b343794c9661c
| | Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:57 2020 -0400
| |     second branch commit
| | 
* | commit d58b010db6ebcad4a911df050947b3e69c165623
| | Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:44 2020 -0400
| |     merged some other branch
| |
| * commit 8b6c93afad0a58ab3c364235f95d1056454ef04c
|/  Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:27 2020 -0400
|       first branch commit
|
* commit a62b7e91f79538ae6d90394fbb888e1986c7f3c0
  Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:09 2020 -0400
      initial commit
```

I want to be able to specify `8b6c93af` and `10d0e777` and just see this log

```
commit 10d0e777e5e660d1c51d9a4f60cdcd5891642b33
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:46:52 2020 -0400
    Merge branch 'branch'

commit ddcc7634e5bbc3d5ebeb67dcbc0cbcafa74aa67e
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:46:41 2020 -0400
    last branch commit

commit 5e86079548fdd3610b80a946cf1b343794c9661c
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:57 2020 -0400
    second branch commit

commit 8b6c93afad0a58ab3c364235f95d1056454ef04c
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:27 2020 -0400
    first branch commit
```

Every git log command I try also shows the commits that were made off of that branch because they *are* in the history of `10d0e777` and come in chronological order. For example

```
git log 8b6c93af..10d0e777

commit 10d0e777e5e660d1c51d9a4f60cdcd5891642b33 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: ac69788 ddcc763
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:46:52 2020 -0400
    Merge branch 'branch'

commit ddcc7634e5bbc3d5ebeb67dcbc0cbcafa74aa67e (branch)
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:46:41 2020 -0400
    last branch commit

commit ac6978892337b20f2548f20d1ad6e0376d609cdb
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:45:11 2020 -0400
    merged another branch

commit 5e86079548fdd3610b80a946cf1b343794c9661c
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:57 2020 -0400
    second branch commit

commit d58b010db6ebcad4a911df050947b3e69c165623
Date:   Thu Aug 27 15:44:44 2020 -0400
    merged some other branch
```

I don't want that. There's no path from `8b6c93af` to `10d0e777` that includes `d58b010db`, so it should not be included in the output.

Comment: Did you try `git log 8b6c93af..10d0e777`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, that has the same output

Comment: Try `--ancestry-path`

Comment: Really? You used `8b6c93af^` before, so something must be different.

Comment: @mkrieger : `git log a..b` will display commits reachable from `b` and not reachable from `a`. In the OP's example, even `git log ddcc763..10d0e777` would include the left branch of its graph (the left branch is not reachable from the right branch).

Comment: You cannot use `8b6c93af` to exclude either of the first-parent commits `ac6978892337b20f2548f20d1ad6e0376d609cdb` or `d58b010db6ebcad4a911df050947b3e69c165623`, as `8b6c93af` is not a descendant of those commits. It's related only by "marriage", as it were, at the merge. Use the first parent of the merge, as LeGEC says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the "right branch" of a merge commit, here is a way :

```
# take the log between the *first* parent of the merge commit
# and the merge commit :
git log 10d0e777^..10d0e777
```

The above command is not very intuitive (you have to know what commits are merge commits, and prune the branch you want to avoid), another possibility is to use `--ancestry-path` :

```
# at least you get to name the commits you are seeing :
git log --ancestry-path 8b6c93af..10d0e777
```

Note that this second option will skip the very first commit (`8b6c93af` in your case) though.

---

*some explanations*

You can read the docs of [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) :

`a..b` is another way to write `^a b` (note that the `^` is placed *before* `a`, not *after*) ;
and `^a b` means : any commit reachable from `b`, and not reachable from `a`.
"reachable" means : the commit itself, or any of its ancestors.

With the above definition, you can take a second look at your `git log` command :

if you mention any commit on the "right side" of the merge commit (`8b6c93a, 5e86079 or ddcc763`) as the `a` above, the commits on the "left side" (`d58b010 and ac69788`) will always be included : these two commits are *not* reachable from the right side.

You can use the [`--ancestry-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---ancestry-path) option, which works only when you specify one single `a..b` range, and which also rejects commits which are not *children* of `a`.
Note that this option still rejects `a` itself, the starting commit will not be part of the resulting list.

Another way is to exclude the history of the first parent (the leftmost child) :

```
# from a merge commit M :
git log M^..M
```

that way, you will exclude all the commits on the "left side" of the merge commit, and keep all the commits on the "right side".